# Does a name patch on a dissipative ESD smock also have to be ESD compliant?

Tags: esd, compliance

Does a name patch on a ESD smock also have to be ESD compliant?

Comment: What threat does it pose?

Comment: We work with a lot of tiny microchips and tiny components in our warehouse. And theyre directly in contact with these parts.

Comment: What is directly in contact with the parts, the patches or the people wearing the patches?  I don't see any reason that a name patch needs to be ESD compliant, as long as its not excessively large or in frequent contact with parts.

Comment: Since you are asking about ESD smock and name patches, that suggests you work for a company. A company will normally have an ESD program manager / coordinator who you go to, in order to get answers to questions about the ESD procedures in *that* company. In this situation, it doesn't matter what someone says here - you would be required to follow your company standard. So what happened when you asked the person responsible for ESD procedures in your company, for a decision? If you didn't ask them, why not? Or did you ask them, but you want a different answer here? In short, please add context.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what level of ESD compliance. In industries like areospace or medical, the answer would be yes, it would have to be compliant and made of ESD free material or be made conductive. For some industries, no because the cost of ESD protection is not worth the cost of the manufactured electronics.

Even though the tag would probably not be dangerous, it static electric fields could build up charge on the surface to thousands of volts depending on the material.

You could find out by testing one with an electric field meter with the appropriate impedance to see if it really is a problem and violates the ESD requirements at your locale.